# Lazy loading or linq query?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

As the topic says I wonder what is faster and better approach.

Linq and new method in repository like GetCourts(int clubId)

```
var courts =_context.Courts.Where(c=>c.ClubId==clubId)
```

Or lazy loading using EF

```
var courts= _clubRepository.GetClub(clubId).Courts;
```

My Club entity:

```
public class Club :EntityBase
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Court> Courts { get; set; }
    }
```

My Court entity:

```
public class Court:EntityBase
    {
       public bool IsIndoor { get; set; }

       public int ClubId { get; set; }
       public virtual Club Club { get; set; }

       public int CourtTypeId { get; set; }
       public virtual CourtType CourtType { get; set; }
    }
```

I don't knwo what approach to use in my project.

Comment: Lazy loading will be slower in your example because you're making two queries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the use case you describe in your question, using a LINQ query will be much faster than using lazy loading.

This statement:

```
var courts= _clubRepository.GetClub(clubId).Courts;
```

is equivalent to these statements:

```
var club = _clubRepository.GetClub(clubId);
var courts = club.Courts;
```

The first line causes a SQL query to be issued to get a single club with `ClubId == clubId`. The second line causes another SQL query to be issued to get all courts with `ClubId == clubId`. The fact that you are making two queries will overwhelm any potential benefits from the fact that lazy loading uses `sp_executesql`.

On the other hand,

```
var courts =_context.Courts.Where(c=>c.ClubId==clubId)
```

will result in only one SQL query being issued, which will be much more efficient.

Of course, if you already have an instance of `Club` in memory, you should use lazy loading to get its related entities, both for efficiency and to keep your object graph consistent.

Answer (score 3):

Lazy loading will wrap the query in `sp_executesql`, while using normal linq query it will send the t-sql statement directly.

And msdn states that `sp_executesql` will reuse existing execution plan, that means if application sends subsequent query, it helps reducing the overhead.

> Using sp_executesql can help reduce this overhead and still let SQL
>   Server reuse execution plans. sp_executesql can be used instead of
>   stored procedures when executing a Transact-SQL statement several
>   times, when the only variation is in the parameter values supplied to
>   the Transact-SQL statement. Because the Transact-SQL statements
>   themselves remain constant and only the parameter values change, the
>   SQL Server query optimizer is likely to reuse the execution plan it
>   generates for the first execution. - [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Lazy loading is a feature which you can do and load the navigation when it's needed, if you use normal query, you end up having additional code to re-connect all objects.